# Make Chrome automatically click on a specific link on a specific website

Tags: google-chrome, automation, google-chrome-extensions

I need to configure Google Chrome to click on a specific link on a specific website (or even better, websites in a specific domains), just to automate something I have to use all the time.

Is there any Chrome extension I could use?

Answer (score 8):

You can try [iMacros for Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/imacros-for-chrome/cplklnmnlbnpmjogncfgfijoopmnlemp?hl=en). The extension, once added to Chrome, allows you to "record" your navigation and click path. Once you have that in place, you are able to trigger the macro instruction anytime you want.

Here's an example of how you can use the extension: http://youtu.be/RxnH_i2zi1I?hd=1

---

*Would have liked to ask for clarification, however, I was not able to comment.*